# Correct settings for 3D model in aframe.io

Tags: aframe

I'm struggling to get the right settings for a 3D model in A-Frame. It looks great in the A-Frame web inspector and that's the look I would like to have. I tried to change a few inline render parameters, but nothing worked out. Is there a setting to use the standard material params of the model?

[image: left: render view | right: view in the inspector]

Comment: It is a little hard to tell from the image but it looks like you have either a very bright environment or are missing an environment texture.
The tool [Gestaltor](https://gestaltor.io/) is pretty helpful for more in depth analysis of models. If the model looks correct there, than the issue is with your scene, not your model.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and solution for this. I was testing different A-Frame versions and found one (1.4.*) which shows the model correctly. Somehow, it only works for me with the GLB format, but that's fine. It was a bit like trial and error.

Comment: Do you have a link to the model? Is am curious as it seems unlikely to me it only works in 1.4 since I can not find anything in the changelogs that would explain it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this was a purchased model. But I run tests on different machines and browsers, it's the same result. It's working with version 1.3 and above, everything below produced the same. I've checked the changelog on GitHub, but couldn't figure.